# Can't access json data with all possible way

Tags: json

The following line is the outcome of `console.log(response);`
  {result: "{"otp":4016}"}

[image]

Now I want to retrieve the value of otp as follows:

```
response.result.otp
```

it produces undefined. I tried as follows too:

```
response.result['otp']
```

same problem persist.I also explore `response.result` which produces:

```
{"otp":4016}
```

whats problem is going on? any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: You have to parse the result field, as of now its a string

Comment: JSON.parse(response.result).otp should do it

Comment: res => res.json()

Comment: Yes. I parse the result field and it works like a charm